# Pulling most recent result from a one to many join in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am working on a web app and I have a database with two tables.  One of them is called entities and the other is activities.  It is a one to many relationship where there are many entities in the activities table.  The activities table has a date associated with it and I want to pull results based on  certain entity id's but I only want to pull the most recent activity (by its date).  So basically, I only want one return per entity.  There must be a way to do this in mysql without parsing out the data with php.  I want to make the app as fast as possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing at field names ...

```
SELECT 
 e.*, a.*
FROM 

(SELECT 
   MAX(ActivityID) ActivityID,
   EntityID
FROM 
   Activity
GROUP By
  EntityID) maxActivity

INNER JOIN Activity a
ON maxActivity.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
INNER JOIN Entity e
ON e.EntityID = a.EntityID
```

Or if ID isn't always the latest and you really want date (assuming two activities can't share the same date)

```
    SELECT 
     e.*, a.*
    FROM
 (SELECT 
       MAX(Date) Date, 
       EntityID
    FROM 
       Activity
    GROUP By
      EntityID) maxActivity

    INNER JOIN Activity a
    ON maxActivity.Date = a.Date
       and maxActivity.EntityID = a.EntityID 
    INNER JOIN Entity e
    ON e.EntityID = a.EntityID
```

Comment: The dates are not unique but the first one helped.  So I would just get the max ID from the select in the parentheses and join based on that.  I didnt know u could nest select statements.  Does anyone know where I can find more examples of advnaced querying like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, create a linking table through a PK / FK relationship.

So for instance: 
[entities table]     ------ [ent_activities]   --- [activities] , especially since the two data is so intertwined.

1:M is a horrible data integrity issue and even more so when you have 10s, even hundreds of 1:M throughout.

Good luck

Comment: Having an intermediate table doesn't change the problem